# How I can access in Actionscript the "text" property of a TLF text created in the Flash IDE

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, text, textfield, tlf

I created a TLF Text with the Flash IDE in the main document.
I've assigned it an instance name with the IDE

When I try to access the text with Actionscript I cannot access the text field.
Of course if I transform in the IDE the text in classic dynamic text it works as expected

I feel very stupid and I suspect it has an obvious solution but I cannot find any info about the subject

```
// instance name is "myText"

trace(this.myText);
>> null

trace(this.getChildAt(0));    
>> [object Movie Clip]

trace(this.getChildbyName("myText"));
>> null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code might be of help.

```
var markup:XML = 
    <TextFlow xmlns='http://ns.adobe.com/textLayout/2008'>
        some text...
    </TextFlow>;
var flow:TextFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(markup, TextConverter.TEXT_LAYOUT_FORMAT);
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
flow.fontFamily = 'font name...'
flow.flowComposer.addController(new ContainerController(sprite, width, height));
flow.flowComposer.updateAllControllers();

parent object.addChild(sprite);
sprite.x = some
sprite.y = where
```

Comment: Thanks! You open my mind. I finally found the Actionscript manual page [for Displaying Content with Flow Composer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3_Flex/WSc3ff6d0ea7785946579a18b01205e1c5646-7ff2.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you work on the flash class.

I cannot access the TLF Text instance on flash class code but it works on ActionScript in frame. Edit the code in ACTIONS - FRAME.

Comment: Cannot attach script to frame because I was need to access the text from a custom class.